# Combinations of $6$ labeled balls in $4$ labeled boxes with an "extra" condition

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not good at maths and my school days happened a long time ago.

I'm wondering how many combinations of $6$ labeled balls in $4$ labeled buckets can be.

Also (if you can answer it thus it's not crucial for me at the moment) how many combinations could exist in the previous problem if we took into account that each bucket contains $2$ labeled bags in it and balls should be in one of these bags. (there are no restriction of amounts per bag nor per bucket ).

Comment: Do you mean that balls are different?

Comment: Yes, balls are different

Comment: then the first question gives us the answer 6^4

Comment: @TahaAkbari No, it is $4^6$ - the other way round.

Comment: Do you mean the bages are fixed in the box?Any way I wrote both answers.But it isn't clear that bags are fixed or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each ball can independently go into one of the $4$ buckets, so by the multiplication principle there are $4^6=2^{12}=4096$ ways to put the balls into the buckets. If each bucket contains two labelled bags, that's equivalent to there being $8$ buckets, so in that case the count is $8^6=2^{18}=262144$.

Comment: so simple to pass from one bucket to bucket with bags, i've got amazed

Comment: thank you (I cannot upvote)

Comment: @user3612775 But you can check the answer - I think.

Comment: @user3612775: Two other users provided answers based on two other interpretations of the question. My interpretation was that each labelled bucket contains two labelled bags, and the balls are free to go into any of the bags without restrictions (including possibly leaving some bags empty or possibly using both bags in one bucket). In that case, we are effectively simply distributing the balls over $8$ labelled bags without restrictions.

Comment: joriki , your interpretation is the one I meant

Answer (score 0):

The first Question gives us the answer $4^6$ because balls and buckets are different.In the second Question There are 8 bags to go to if you mean the bags are fixed then we have 8^6 ways but if you mean they arn't fixed we have:

from the 8 bags two of them with $7*8\2$ ways can go into first box for second box there is $6*5\2$ ways and so on.Then we have $8^6*28*15*6$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

$(i)$

Each ball has $4$ choices of buckets, so by the multiplication principle,
number of ways $= 4^6 = 4096$

$(ii)$

I am interpreting "balls should be in **one** of these bags" to mean in **only one** bag per box:
Then there are two choices of the bag into which they are put for each box,
and number of ways $= 4096*2^4 = 65,536$

Comment: why 2^4 in the second part?

Comment: If the intent was that balls can be put in more than one bag per box, of course, the answer will be as given by joriki. $2^4$ is for the interpretation that **only one bag per box is used.**

Comment: But it wrote : each bucket contains 2 labeled bags

Comment: Yes, but why not then simply write $8$ labelled bags ? I found the wording ambiguous, so just provide an answer for another possible interpretation.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: Note that for the second part, labelling of boxes/buckets has no relevance unless only one bag per box/bucket is used.